# htaccess redirect only root domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect my domain name from one site to another. I only want the rule to be applied if no other subpages are specified

EG:

```
www.example.com
```

would get redirected

```
www.example.com/folder/page.php
```

would not get redirected

The code I have does a catch all and that is not what I want

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/folder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://newsite.com/folder/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, will this ensure www.oldsite.com/folder/page.php still resolve without redirecting?

Comment: Yes `www.oldsite.com/folder/page.php` remains unaffected

Comment: Is the question mark needed in the regular expression in line 2 of your snippet? `^/$` is enough if you only want to match `/`. Also my simplified regex example does work in Apache 2.4.

Comment: `^/?$` was used to make this rule compatible from htaccess as well as from Apache config. `^/$` won't work inside .htaccess